# Fail to connect to postgres database by node.js through VS code

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Lately I am trying to connect my node.js program to postgres database through VS Code. But I got below error message. I tried several methods following info acquired from google but didn't resolve. Would someone with experience can share a tip about how to resolve this issue?

Server is running at http://localhost:3000
node:internal/process/promises:288
triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
^

Error: connect EACCES ::1:5432
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1495:16) {
errno: -4092,
code: 'EACCES',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '::1',
port: 5432
}

Node.js v18.17.1

resolve the issue so that I can keep developing.

Comment: This is trying to connect via IPv6.  Does your Postgres instance listen on IPv6?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.